# How create responsive email that send from php?

Tags: php, html, css, email

How to create responsive email just like [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xdvdw.png)

I see many responsive email have same design which the content in the middle and there is space in right and left side with different color. When the email opened in the mobile device the space in the right and left are gone. Looks like they create it with same way that i dont know how. I send email using php like this

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(); 
$mail->IsSMTP(); 
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;  
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; 
$mail->Host = "xxxx";
$mail->Port = xxx; 
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "xxxx";
$mail->Password = "xxxxx";
$mail->SetFrom("xxxx");
$mail->Subject = "xxxx";
$mail->Body = $htmlContent;
$mail->AddAddress("xxxx@gmail.com");
```

**$htmlContent** is the template of html. I've read some information that the css must be inline styles or wouldn't loaded. But if it was inlines then how to use some library like bootstrap, etc. I really beginner about this. Any helps will be apreciated. Thanks.

Comment: For such a thing I would use a packagist package. https://packagist.org/packages/emielmolenaar/transactional-email-templates. It's a pain to create it :-p.

Comment: It's pretty irrelevant how you *send* the email. The only thing that matters is the content of `$htmlContent`. And yes, creating cross-compatible HTML for email clients is **a major pain in the rear** because you're limited to some narrow subset of supported HTML.

Comment: @deceze Thanks, i will focus in $htmlContent. I didn't imagine before it would be very difficult.

Comment: @RonnieOosting Thanks for helpful information. You should move it to answer so i can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I would not try to create something like this on your own. There are many awesome packages you can use. I will note some for you:

- https://packagist.org/packages/emielmolenaar/transactional-email-templates
- https://packagist.org/packages/swiftmailer/swiftmailer
- https://packagist.org/packages/phpmailer/phpmailer

Or

- https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Good luck! :-)

Comment: i find css inliner tool like https://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/inline-css/. It will help to convert the css easier.